# Image 100%/100% how to disable zoom on mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I need to have an image to be 100% width and 100% height and position fixed. Everything works fine but i have some problems on mobile device. For Example on Iphone, when I use the zoom the image zooms and a moment later it skips back to 100%/100%. 
How can I avoid this and lets say disable zooming for a special div? Or is it better to work with jquery to make the shape-div same size as viewport? Or…?

```
.shape{

width: 100%;
height: 100%;

z-index: 2; //there are elements under this shape
position:fixed; 

left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;

background-image: url("shape.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

background-origin: content-box;
background-position:center;
}
```

A next problem is: when Safari displayed the navigation bar the Shape changed its size (that makes sense) but how can I avoid this?

Thank you so much in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but you can disable the zoom feature entirely with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable the zoom for a single element.

You may do so for the whole document (via the `viewport` meta tag), but that would probably leave some user with an unusable site (as the images and text may be too small…).